# Facebook C# SDK - How to get my details from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

How to connect to my facebook? The SDK accepts only the APP ID. How to get my facebook news, notes and friends list?

Answer (score 0):

The below link can be used as a start up for Facebook C# SDK

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx